# How to get the user agent for a headless browser

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am running my tests on headless chrome browser and need to get the user agent of the headless browser.
For a Chrome browser, that is not headless I use this code to get the user agent:

```
page.execute_script("navigator.userAgent"); ==> which works as required
```

But for a headless browser this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to get the userAgent?

PS: I use ruby, capybara in my framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using `execute_script` when you need to be using `evaluate_script` because you want a response.  That being said, your code shouldn't have worked without headless set either so I'm not sure what version of Capybara you're running.

```
page.evaluate_script("navigator.userAgent")
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It worked great, I realized with execute_script I was returning the useragent from js code and it was working fine. So I had something like this: page.execute_script("var ua = navigator.userAgent;return ua;"). All this feels unnecessary and I have made the changes by using evaluate_script

Comment: @AutomationTester You’re welcome, if the issue is solved don’t forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered.